# Why is the first term of First Law of Black-Hole Thermodynamics in other unit than in joule?

Tags: black-holes, dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion, absolute-units

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics#The_First_Law

http://www.physics.umd.edu/grt/taj/776b/lectures.pdf
(p.13)

The 2 sources have various forms of the same law. I found both are not dimensionally consistent, why?

Comment: Are you familiar with things like Planck units?

Comment: You mean nondimensionalization?

Comment: Just the general ideas of changing different unit systems and how to convert expressions between them etc.

Comment: In the first source, the first term is in m^3s^-2

Comment: In the second source, the first term is in kg.

Comment: I guess the first source just misses the G & c^2, and the second one misses the c^2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in GR equations can get very complicated very quickly it's common practice to simplify then by using a system of units where pretty much every constant is set to unity. These are generally referred to as [geometrised units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system).

The trouble is that people tend to get a bit causal with the units. For example since $E = mc^2$ and in geometrised units $c = 1$ so we have $E = m$ i.e. energy equals mass, and the two tend to be used interchangeably. That's why one of your references given an equation for the energy and the other gives an equation for the mass. You also get partially geometrised equations as in your second reference where $c$ has been set to unity and omitted but $G$ has been explicitly written in the equation even though it's just unity as well.

I don't think there is any special reason why the different authors have written different forms of the same equation. I would guess it's just personal preference.